# Jquery - Only process if field isn't empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

This is my code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/E8sNt/1/

I was wondering for the following function:

```
        if (coded === false) {
                processLocation();
        }
```

How I can get this to execute ONLY if the #loc input field actually has something in it. In sudo code it would be a bit like this, but I can't work out the proper code:

```
        if (coded === false && #loc.val!=0) {
                processLocation();
        }
```

This is my full code:

```
var coded = false;
geocode();
$.cookie("country", "uk");

// GEOCODE FUNCTION
function geocode() {
        var input = $('#loc')[0];
        var options = {types: ['geocode']};
        var country_code = $.cookie('country');

        if (country_code) {
                options.componentRestrictions = {
                        'country': country_code
                };
        }

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                processLocation();
        });

        $('#searchform').on('submit', function(e) {
                if (coded === false) {
                        processLocation();
                }
                return true;
        });

        $("#loc").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
                coded = false;
        });
}

function processLocation() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = $('#loc').val();
        geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
        },
        function(results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        coded = true;
                        $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                        $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                } else {
                        coded = false;
                        alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
                }
        });
//      coded = true;     // Do we need this?
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for providing a JSFiddle link, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (coded === false && $("#loc").val() != "") {
      processLocation();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E8sNt/2/

Or -

```
if(!coded && $('#loc').val()){
  processLocation();
}
```

Comment: Thanks `JAM` and `PlantTheldea`

Comment: one more ... ternary! `(!coded && $("#loc").val()) ? processLocation() : '';`

Comment: With JS if (coded === false && document.getElementById("loc").value!= "")

Comment: Thanks guys! I've put the code up on here too : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26215/first-javascript-geocoder-can-it-be-improved

Answer (score 4):

`$("#loc").val() != ""`
 should work.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (coded === false && $('#loc').val() ) {
      processLocation();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

sorry if I misunderstood but is this what you need ?

```
  if (coded === false && $("#loc").val().length> 0) {
                processLocation();
        }
```

Chears

Answer (score 2):

With Javascript

```
if (coded === false && document.getElementById("loc").value!= "") {
      processLocation();
}
```